Can't use webrtc on expo-go
I cannot use react-native-webrtc. When I open Expo Go, I encounter this error:
Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist.
If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info., js engine: hermes
ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it, and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

What are some good solutions for this, or are there any alternatives to WebRTC?

As mentioned in the official document:

https://i.sstatic.net/KnL4eghG.png

Currently, react-native-webrtc is not supported to expo-go because it contains native modules. However, you can get things working via the expo-dev-client library and the out-of-tree config-plugins/react-native-webrtc package.
